How to add shapefiles and raster files as covariates in spatstat kppm function
I encountered various errors while running the spatstat package. Here is a summary of my data: a shapefile of landslide point events, a watershed shapefile as the observation window, and several covariates (raster files (*.tif): elevation, slope, aspect, and etc, and vector files: landcover$class_name and lithology$FormUnitNa). I need to run several "cox and cluster" models to see which model is best for my data and identify which landcover classes and lithology type are statistically valuable in my analysis. Finally, use a prediction function to generate a landslide susceptibility map for the entire watershed.
    # Install required packages (if not already installed)
    install.packages(c("ggplot2", "sf", "terra", "spatstat", "raster", "stars"))
    
    # Load libraries
    library(ggplot2)
    library(sf)
    library(terra)
    library(spatstat)
    library(raster)
    library(stars)
    
    # Read the shapefiles (ppplandslide is a marked point pattern)
    shp_lslide <- st_read("landslide_v1.shp")
    shp_wshed <- st_read("Watershed_v1.shp")
    shp_litho <- st_read("lithology.shp")
    
    plot(as.layered())
    
    summary(shp_lslide)
    summary(shp_wshed)
    
    # Create a simplified map using ggplot
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = shp_wshed, fill = "lightblue", color = "blue", alpha = 0.5) + 
      geom_sf(data = shp_lslide, color = "red", size = 2) +
      labs(title = "Landslides within Watershed Boundary") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
    
    # Check geometry types (optional)
    st_geometry_type(shp_lslide, by_geometry = FALSE)
    st_geometry_type(shp_wshed, by_geometry = FALSE)
    
    # Convert the landslide centroids to a 'ppp' (point pattern) object
    # First, convert the sf object to a SpatialPoints object, then to ppp
    lslide <- as.ppp(st_as_sf(shp_lslide))
    
    # Convert the watershed shapefile to an 'owin' (observation window) object
    wshed <- as.owin(st_as_sf(shp_wshed))
    
    # Subset the point pattern to include only points within the watershed boundary
    lslide_within_wshed <- lslide[wshed]
    
    lslide_within_wshed <- unmark(lslide_within_wshed)
    # ---- Adding the Elevation Covariate ----
    
    # Load the raster layer (elevation, aspect)
    elevation <- read_stars("DEM_Resample_v2.tif")
    aspect <- read_stars("Aspect_v2.tif")
    slope <- read_stars("Slope_reclass_v3.tif")
    planCurva <- read_stars("PlanCurvature_v2.tif")
    proCurva <- read_stars("ProfileCurvature_Reclass_v1.tif")
    landCover <- read_stars("Land_Cover_v3.tif")
        
    #Convert raster to pixel image
    elevation <- as.im(elevation)
    aspect <- as.im(aspect)
    slope <- as.im(slope)
    planCurva <- as.im(planCurva)
    proCurva <- as.im(proCurva)
    landCover <- as.im(landCover)
    
    plot(elevation)
    plot(slope)
    plot(landCover)
    
    fit1 = kppm(lslide_within_wshed, ~elevation + aspect - 1 + slope -1 + 
              planCurva -1 + proCurva -1 + landCover -1, "Thomas")
    fit2 = kppm(lslide_within_wshed, ~landCover -1, "Thomas")
        
    summary(fit1)
    summary(fit2)

    fitted_intensity <- predict(fit1)
    plot(fitted_intensity, main = "Landslide susceptibility map")


welcome to SO. A good R question should contain code that is a self-contained, minimal, reproducible example. That is, it should not depend on your data (use data that ships with R, see the examples, or create some with code) and it should not include things that are not pertinent to the question (e.g., your ggplot). Can you please fix your question?

You say that you experienced "various errors". Could you please say what the errors were? For example, what was the error message, and at what stage did it occur?
